# storage container access level issue in c# code

Tags: azure

I have a container in storage account and i have changed it's configuration Allow Blob public access
to disabled. And i am using connection string of that container to open the files. When this line is getting executed Stream stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync() , it is throwing an error saying Public access is not permitted on this storage account.

even i tried using SAS token instead of connection string, but getting same issue..

I want my configuration of Allow Blob public access to be disabled and need to access this using my code c#...

```
        var storageConnection = configuration["STORAGE_CONNECTION"];
        var storageContainer = Configuration["StorageContainer"]; 
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
         CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(storageContainer);

        var fileName = file.FileName;
        Console.WriteLine($"Procesing file: {fileName}");

        CloudBlob blob = new CloudBlob(new Uri(fileName));

        var lines = new List<string>();
        
        using (Stream stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string headerLine = reader.ReadLine();
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var bodyLine = reader.ReadLine();
                    lines.Add(bodyLine);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add the code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Where are you using the conectionString?

Comment: How does your Blob URI look like?

Comment: update the question

Comment: @Madhu next time you post a question, please include ALL relevant code from start, it makes it much easier to understand the issue, reproduce it and help out. I suggest that you read what Im posting in my next comment here.

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!).

Comment: You are not using any of the code above this line: CloudBlob blob = new CloudBlob(new Uri(fileName));

Thats your main problem. You just create a new blob without any relation to the CloudBlobClient and CloudBlobContainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some smaller changes this works fine.

```
public static async Task ReadToBlobAsync()
{
    var storageConnection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    var storageContainer = "xxxx";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
    CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(storageContainer);

    var fileName = "test.txt";
    Console.WriteLine($"Procesing file: {fileName}");

    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("testcsv.csv");

    var lines = new List<string>();

    using (Stream stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string headerLine = reader.ReadLine();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var bodyLine = reader.ReadLine();
                lines.Add(bodyLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Madhu copy my code, that code works with Public Access disabled. The problem in your code is that you are creating a new CloudBlob which is not related to the Container and CloudBlobClient. Hence you are not logged in.